# Private Pointer error in C++ linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a linked list in C++, but every time I compile, I get an error that says `'Node* Node::nextPtr' is private`. If I change `nextPtr` to have public protection, then I don't get the error and my list is fine. Can someone tell me why this is and how to fix it? My `list` and `node` classes are as follows:

```
//list.h
#include <string>

#include "node.h"

using namespace std;

class List
{

    public:
            List();

            bool isEmpty();
            void insertAtFront(string Word);
            void displayList();

    private:
            Node * firstPtr;
            Node * lastPtr;

};


//node.h
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Node
{

    public:
            Node(string arg);

            string getData();



    private:
            string data;
            Node * nextPtr;


};


//node.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "node.h"

using namespace std;

Node::Node(string arg)
    :nextPtr(0)
{
    cout << "Node constructor is called" << endl;
    data = arg;

}

string Node::getData()
{
    return data;
}


//list.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "list.h"
#include "node.h"

using namespace std;

List::List()
    :firstPtr(0), lastPtr(0)
{
}

bool List::isEmpty()
{
    if(firstPtr == lastPtr)
            return true;
    else
            return false;
}

void List::displayList()
{
    Node * currPtr = firstPtr;

    do
    {

            if(currPtr->nextPtr == lastPtr) // Error here
                    cout << endl << currPtr->getData() << endl;
            cout << endl << currPtr->getData() << endl;

            currPtr = currPtr->nextPtr; //Error here

    }
    while(currPtr != lastPtr);

}

void List::insertAtFront(string Word)
{

    Node * newPtr = new Node(Word);

    if(this->isEmpty() == true)
    {
            firstPtr = newPtr;
            cout << "Adding first element...." << endl;
    }
    else if(this->isEmpty() == false)
    {
            newPtr->nextPtr = firstPtr; //Error here
            firstPtr = newPtr;
            cout << "Adding another element...." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the line of code with the error?

Comment: drop `friend class List;` just inside the `class Node {` declaration. Or better still, consider making `Node` a private nested class of `class List`, i.e. put it where it belongs.

Comment: I added the implementation files for the two classes at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show the definitions of your member functions inside the `List` class, but I bet it is due to those member functions try to access `nextPtr` from the Node class. You can,

1. make `nextPtr` public from `Node`
2. add public accessor functions to `Node` to access it
3. declare `List` as a friend from `Node`, `friend class List;`

Comment: Thank you! I used the `friend class List;` method to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Because somewhere in your code, you access `Node * nextPtr` by non member functions of class `Node`.  You can create a `getter` for `nextPrt` to avoid that.